# Strange error when compiling matplotlib with PyQt4 via pyinstaller

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt4, pyinstaller

My headaches of trying to compile PyQt4 and Matplotlib are seeming pretty endless.

Here is my test program `test.py`

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import math
import sys

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and here is my attempt to freeze this file by the command line
`pyinstaller -w --onefile test.py`
(tested with no options - `pyinstaller test.py` - with identical results)

And here is my console output:

```
16 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Tyson\Desktop\PHS3031 Lab1.2 - Alpha\test.spec
30 INFO: Testing for ability to set icons, version resources...
46 INFO: ... resource update available
62 INFO: UPX is not available.
78 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
171 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
171 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
233 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
328 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
405 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
421 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
717 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with C:\Users\Tyson\Desktop\PHS3031 Lab1.2 - Alph
a
717 INFO: checking Analysis
796 INFO: checking PYZ
826 INFO: checking PKG
826 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
826 INFO: building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\main.py", line 88, in run
    run_build(opts, spec_file, pyi_config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\main.py", line 46, in run_buil
d
    PyInstaller.build.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **opts.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\build.py", line 1924, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'
))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\build.py", line 1873, in build

    execfile(spec)
  File "C:\Users\Tyson\Desktop\PHS3031 Lab1.2 - Alpha\test.spec", line 17, in <m
odule>
    console=False )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\build.py", line 1170, in __ini
t__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\build.py", line 1008, in __ini
t__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\build.py", line 309, in __post
init__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\build.py", line 1050, in assem
ble
    dist_nm=inm)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\build.py", line 842, in checkC
ache
    digest = cacheDigest(fnm)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\build.py", line 796, in cacheD
igest
    data = open(fnm, "rb").read()
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: ''
```

I'm attempting to do this on Windows 7 with Python 2.7.

It appears there's some empty string which was expected to be a filename, but this error obviously exists outside my code.

Any and all help appreciarted.
Thanks,
Tyson

Comment: did you try updating pywin32, it looks like the egg version can cause problems (2 cases)

Comment: I updated pywin32 with pip initially with no luck

Comment: no problems on my machine, see complete output https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvp1hfq381j0i9h/test1.txt?dl=0

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm running into a similar problem. See my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433814/debugging-pyqt-executable-compiled-with-pyinstaller

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the PyInstaller is having a problem with the cache which it uses to not read all the sourcefiles every time.

In the %Appdata% folder is a pyinstaller folder which store the cache in the bincache* folder. Maybe it helps to clean the cache and try again to run the pyinstaller

Comment: Had no effect whatsoever