# Debugging PyQt executable compiled with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an PyQt executable using pyinstaller.  I am using python 2.7 on Windows 7 and using PyCharm.

I am using the example code from here: https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/simple-pyqt-and-matplotlib-example-with-zoompan/

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random


class Window(QtGui.QDialog):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

    self.figure = plt.figure()
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
    self.toolbar.hide()

    # Just some button
    self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Plot')
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)

    self.button1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Zoom')
    self.button1.clicked.connect(self.zoom)

    self.button2 = QtGui.QPushButton('Pan')
    self.button2.clicked.connect(self.pan)

    self.button3 = QtGui.QPushButton('Home')
    self.button3.clicked.connect(self.home)

    # set the layout
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
    layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
    layout.addWidget(self.button)
    layout.addWidget(self.button1)
    layout.addWidget(self.button2)
    layout.addWidget(self.button3)
    self.setLayout(layout)

def home(self):
    self.toolbar.home()

def zoom(self):
    self.toolbar.zoom()

def pan(self):
    self.toolbar.pan()

def plot(self):
    data = [random.random() for i in range(25)]
    ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    ax.hold(False)
    ax.plot(data, '*-')
    self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

main = Window()
main.setWindowTitle('Simple QTpy and MatplotLib example with Zoom/Pan')
main.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is what I am running in the command line:

```
pyinstaller.exe --debug --windowed mainUI.py
```

There is no error when opening.  I click through the debug process, but the program does not open.  My guess is that there is something I need to add to the .spec, but I do not know what to add.

Why won't the program open or give an error?

Comment: Remove the `--windowed` option to show the console and run your `.exe` from the command line. The error will show up.